# Paginate data from relationship model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.6

Apologies if the title doesn't completely make sense... I wasn't sure if the exact terminology for the linking of models are the associated data in their controllers.

I'm trying to paginate a table with the posts created by a user.

I managed to paginate it previously, without the user_id in the posts table. But I've added the `user_id` to the `posts` table, and run the migration which works fine.

The following is my `Post` model:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Post extends Model
    {
      public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }
    }
```

And this is my `User` model:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;
        protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password',];

        protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];

        public function posts() {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
        }
    }
```

And this is the relevant section of the post controller:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Post;
    use App\User;
    use Session;
    use Carbon\Carbon;

    class PostController extends Controller
    {

      public function index()
      {

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $user->posts);
      }
```

I thought that it would simply be a case of appending `->paginate(5)` to the `$user` in the `PostController`, but that doesn't appear to work.

I get the following:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$posts
```

I've tried including the `{!! $posts->links() !!}` in the `posts.index` view before the `@foreach` but that gives:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$posts
```

I'm trying to learn Laravel basics by creating this crud application, and have tried combining two tutorials together, but I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `->paginate()` on the relationship like this (also I've removed the unnecessary user query, since `auth()->user()` will execute it already):

```
public function index()
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $posts = $user->posts()->paginate();
    // Or with 1 line: $posts = auth()->user()->posts()->paginate();
    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```